# How to access Gradle property in Dockerfile of Spring Boot application

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, gradle, dockerfile

I have a Spring Boot application with Gradle as a build tool and org.sglahn:gradle-dockerfile-plugin which I use to build and pull docker images

Everything works fine until this point

I have a property in build.gradle file which I use to set up build version number:

```
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

I'm trying to access version property from Dockerfile but it is not available there:

```
FROM openjdk:9
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/configserver
ADD /build/libs/config-server-${project.version}.jar /usr/local/configserver/
ADD run.sh run.sh
RUN chmod +x run.sh
CMD ./run.sh
```

I expect to see replaced value on the third line of Dockerfile but it doesn't happen. I get the following error:

> Step 3/6 : ADD /build/libs/config-server-${project.version}.jar
>   /usr/local/configserver/ failed to process
>   "/build/libs/config-server-${project.version}.jar": missing ':' in
>   substitution

I also tried to put version property in gradle.properties file but this doesn't help either

When I replace the line with real build filename everything works as expected

`ADD /build/libs/config-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Can anybody advise please how to access gradle property in Dockerfile

Comment: Running a Dockerfile is done with `docker` and not gradle. So you can't use groovy syntax variables like `${project.version}`. You could try to define a system property (similar to `export myServiceVersion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`) in gradle which the Dockerfile could then use